# Addition of new javascript results in graph not being recognised in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've added a new peice of javascript to an old script I had to add a highlighting functionality to a force network layout. I get the information for the diagram from generated json in a rails app. The original code I've been using is here:

```
   var width = 960,
    height = 960;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-100)
    .linkDistance(530)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var endpoint = window.location.href+".json"

d3.json(endpoint, function(graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("marker-end",  "url(#suit)");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('dblclick', connectedNodes);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 25)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
    .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
    .style("opacity", "0.6");
    
    //APPENDED CODE ADDED HERE


  //Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
var toggle = 0;
//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});
//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}
function connectedNodes() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        //Reduce the op
        toggle = 1;
    } else {
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        toggle = 0;
    }
}
```

I then tried to append further code as suggested [here](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/) and simply added the following to the bottom of the script above where it is marked in capital letters

Could have been so simple.... The script worked but the added functionlity (to add highlights between nodes) didn't. An error message says:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: graph is not defined
```

My susipicion is that it relates to the line

```
  d3.json(endpoint, function(graph) {
```

and the fact that the subsequent }); is in the wrong place to encompass the new code but I've played with it and I'm not sure how to correct it

## UPDATE

I've solved this. The problem was simply that I was declaring graph inside a function and the other functions couldn't access it. The solution is to put the other functions inside the function that delares it which in effect means moving the last

});

from the line

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
      });
    });
```

to the very last line. Works fine now

Comment: Can you post your full code as it is now - it's not clear if the new block was added at the end within the parentheses or outside it. You can just paste it in a fiddle (even if it doesn't work)

Comment: Have pasted the code as is into the question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is now given in the UPDATE section of the question

Comment: The answer should be posted as an answer, not in the question. Would you mind doing that please?